# How I can set direction as only Tx message should be there and filter out TxRq

Tags: capl, req, tx

I am writing a CAPL script to mimic a CAN message on network. While I am getting intended message, direction is both Tx & TxRq. How I can filter out and send only Tx message.

I tried CANID.dir=1 (tx) however not getting intended result.

[Message details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOPeM.png)

I tried, setting direction as CANID.dir=1 (tx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot, I assume took from the Trace window, you are looking at duplicate entries that spark confusion.

The entries marked as `Tx` are telling you that there is, indeed, a CAN frame with direction "outgoing" from your measurement system (your Vector Node).

The entries marked as `TxRq` are send requests. You may change settings for send requests in the Vector Hardware Configuration tool ([ref](https://cdn.vector.com/cms/content/products/VectorCAST/Events/TechNights/CANalyzer_QuickStart.pdf)).

`TxRq` is not a "direction" per se, just a way to indicate a different type of log in the Trace window. Remember that the only directions available are `Tx` and `Rx` (all frames either go *out* of your node or come *into* your node).

More about send requests. The following is an extract, I don't remember from which Vector knowledge base entry

> By default, this box [the one in the Vector Hardware Configuration] is unchecked because most users do not require
> this feature. This feature displays the `TxRq` messages with a time
> stamp in the Trace window of CANoe. These are requests to send
> messages by CANoe that have not yet been transmitted onto the CAN bus.
> If they have been transmitted on the CAN bus, they would be `Tx`
> messages.

Comment: please open a separate question for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Vector Network Hardware Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eniMT.png)

If you get similar issue, pls go to simulation setup, channel on which you have simulated node, go to Network hardware & untick Activate TxRq